# Django aggregate and grouping : code cleanliness problem 

Tags: python, django, group-by

Here is a small problem I am having.

---

3 very simple models :

```
>>> class Instrument(models.Model):
...     name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
... 
>>> class Musician(models.Model):
...     instrument = models.ForeignKey(Instrument)
... 
>>> class Song(models.Model):
...     author = models.ForeignKey(Musician)
```

I would like to *count the number of songs, grouped by instrument name and by author*

---

I have solutions to it, but I would like to know what is the best way to write it in pure django-orm, such as the code would be clean, concise and reusable (I mean something that you can easily re-use to group by different attributes). What I am actually trying to see is if some code I have written to solve this problem generically is really useful, or if I just missed something big ...

Here's the first solution I think of :

```
results = []
for instrument_name in Instrument.objects.values_list('instrument', flat=True):
    for musician in Musician.objects.filter(instrument__name=instrument_name):
        results.append((
            instrument_name,
            musician,
            Song.objects.filter(author=musician).count())
        )
```

Thank you for your help !!!

Comment: Why the -1 please ? Did I break any rule ?

Comment: I didn't give you the -1, but I'd suggest writing it as a "I'm trying to do X, but am not sure how - can you help?" instead of as a challenge with a bunch of rules. You're asking for help, not running a code competition.

Comment: Sure ... But on the other hand, I know answers to my question ! What I would really like to know is what is the best way to solve this problem with pure django-orm... Maybe I should just write this !

Comment: right, it could be "this works but is ugly.  is there any better way?"

Comment: Ok ... I edited the question to make it "politically correct".

Comment: I voted -1 because I thought you should have posted your attempt. Perhaps I was being a bit harsh. I've removed the downvote now that you've updated the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from [Django docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/aggregation/#values):

```
from django.db.models import Count
Song.objects.values('author','author__instrument').annotate(Count("id"))
```

I'm not 100% sure it will work (it's 2:20 AM), but I hope so.

Comment: It does, the key to aggregation in Django IS the use of .values before the aggregation, Django uses this to build the "group by" clause